# Codeigniter radio buttons does not work [PHP,HTML]

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am creating test project with codeigniter and i am struggling with radio buttons and options.
I would like to create advance question form with for example 6 different radio buttons selects and input labels such name, surname etc (which i successfully achieved)

When i fill necessary fields and set test radio button to proper value and hit submit button simply nothing happen and. I can't find what causes the problem.

I am using here form helper (that says documentation to use set_radio)

I tried to use form_radio, set_radio etc. You will find my examples below

Here is my view (i didn't paste text input because that part is working)

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
        $attributes = array(
            "name" => "registrationform",
            "id" => "msform"
            );
        echo form_open("yourself/register", $attributes);
    ?>
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active"><span class="circle">1</span> APPLY</li>
        <li class="active"><span class="circle">2</span> FORM</li>
        <li><span class="circle">3</span> CHECK</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- FORM Yourself -->
    <fieldset>

        <div class="input-box">
            <h2 class="title">What licence would you like?</h2>
            <input type="radio" name="what_licence" value="1" <?php echo  set_radio('what_licence', '1', TRUE); ?> /> Black and white?</label>
            <input type="radio" name="what_licence" value="2" <?php echo  set_radio('what_licence', '2'); ?> /> Colour?</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Signup</button>
            <button name="cancel" type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
    <!-- FORM Yourself -->
    </form>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
</div>
<!-- row -->
```

Here is my controller

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('what_licence', 'What licence', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('initials', 'Initials', 'trim|required|alpha');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[3]|max_length[30]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email ID', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[yourself.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('tel_number', 'Phone Number', 'required|numeric|min_length[9]|callback_uk_phone_check');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric_spaces');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('post-code', 'Post Code', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric_spaces');


        $data = array(
            'what_licence' => $this->input->post('what_licence'),
            'initials' => $this->input->post('initials'),
            'lastname' => $this->input->post('lastname'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'tel_number' => $this->input->post('tel_number'),
            'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
            'post-code' => $this->input->post('post-code'),
        );
```

'what_licence' is for radio button which does not work
If you could advise me it would be great. I am getting bald that doesn't work
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is: $this->form_validation->run() ?

My code (is ok):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('what_licence', 'What licence', 'required|in_list[1,2]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('initials', 'Initials', 'trim|required|alpha');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[3]|max_length[30]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email ID', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[yourself.email]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('tel_number', 'Phone Number', 'required|numeric|min_length[9]|callback_uk_phone_check');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric_spaces');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('post-code', 'Post Code', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric_spaces');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            echo "SUCCESS FORM";
            $data = array(
                'what_licence' => $this->input->post('what_licence'),
                'initials'     => $this->input->post('initials'),
                'lastname'     => $this->input->post('lastname'),
                'email'        => $this->input->post('email'),
                'tel_number'   => $this->input->post('tel_number'),
                'address'      => $this->input->post('address'),
                'post-code'    => $this->input->post('post-code'),
            );
            print_r($data);
        }else {
            echo validation_errors();
        }
```

Pozdrawiam mistrzu :)

Comment: Thanks for answering :-) but i have         if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            // fails
            $this->load->view('yourself_registration_view');
        }

Comment: That is the problem that i can't find where is problem. It seems to be everything good but still when i hit submit button just scroll me on the top of website. Do you think radio imput fields in view are correctly written (set_radio)? Pozdrawiam :-)

Comment: Your code html is ok.

Look for my example: 
Controller: http://pastebin.com/c5geSTRA
View: http://pastebin.com/KKJ6Qd7B

Comment: ahhh i figure it out! Thanks to You Arkadiusz! many many thanks

Comment: I have best practice code for you (bootstrap form, controller).
Look: http://pastebin.com/2D5zY4AS

Pozdrawiam :)

Comment: That's clarify me a lot and now i am using something similar to code you proposed. Thank You again, You are star!